# lxc-unfreeze does not resume the guest if the host is rebooted

Tags: linux, lxc

Does a guest that has been frozen with lxc-freeze survive a reboot of the host?

I.e. after rebooting the host, can the guest be unfrozen with lxc-unfreeze?